# What is wrong with this css selector?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css, angular-material

The Angular Material tabs component has some very bad performance issues when using the "Dynamic height" option, this is also clearly on their [demo page here](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/tabs).

The first tab on their demo page has the dynamic height, If you swap to the second tab (because it has more content) and scroll up and down you can feel the scroll lagging, if you scroll past the first tab and over the others, it doesn't do it. I ended up digging through the source code, and while it did take me about 2 hours to find, it turned out to be a single css property that's killing it.

On that same demo page, if you just run this in your console, you'll see the instant performance increase when scrolling.

`angular.element(document.querySelector('md-tabs.md-dynamic-height md-tabs-content-wrapper')).css('overflow', 'hidden')`

This baffles me, because their css is setting the overflow to visible which is the default, yet someone `hidden` is fixing this performance issue, which I'd absolutely love to know how/why!

Any help would be very grateful!

Comment: I'm not sure, but as the `md-tabs.md-dynamic...` are `attributes` so we need to use `[ tag ] ` (Square Brackets) for them ? like `[md-tabs md-dynamic]`

Comment: Sorry @DeepakYadav? It's a css selector, matching what's already in the dom

Comment: Hmm.. Can't reproduce this, doesn't feels laggy for me on Firefox, neither in Chrome.

Comment: @GerardReches Can you please try going into your chrome settings under advanced options and uncheck "Use hardware acceleration where available", I can't re-produce normally either until I check this box.

Comment: Hardware acceleration disabled and it still looks ok

Comment: And you swapped to the second tab item on their page @GerardReches? I have a very good computer, and can notice a definite lag on my machine in chrome, latest chrome, all the laptops at work have it and I'm not the only one to report bad performance with the dynamic-height attribute on material tab component

Comment: Yup. Windows 10 64 bits, i7-6700K 4GHz, NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080.

Comment: This baffles me, but I can definitely see a huge performance change